# External inline filters, markdown, latex, beamer, and standards

Tags: beamer, shell-escape, markdown, unix

I read [Converting Markdown to LaTeX, in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101717/converting-markdown-to-latex-in-latex) and a couple of related posts.  They are about a year old.

is there now a quasi-standard package that enables generic filter plugins, allowed if \write18 is enabled?  I mean

```
\begin{filter}{pandoc -o tex}
   ...
\end{filter}
```

filter should be standard unix filtering from stdin to stdout, and preferably without slow temporary files or preprocessing.  given such a filter package, if it defined

```
\newenvironment{md}{\begin{filter}{pandoc -o tex}}{\end{filter}}
\newenvironment{mdframe}[2]{\begin{frame}[#1]{#2} \begin{md}}{\end{md}}
```

then the emacs auctex maintainers may support this eventually, too.  (actually, this is why I think this could/should be part of the standard filter.sty .)

it does not seem a good idea for amateurs to hack their own versions for something that solves a class of fairly common problems and goes deep into the OS/latex interface.  having this designed by the pros and having it standard would be a blessing.

is this in the cards?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `bashful` package does this and a bit more.