# A better way to do nested lists

Tags: lists, syntax, nesting

This is how you type set a nested list in LaTeX:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item I have a house
    \begin{itemize}
        \item It has 4 walls
        \item a roof,
        \item two windows,
        \item and a door
        \begin{itemize}
            \item with a handle
            \item and a lock
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \item I also have a car
    \begin{itemize}
        \item but I will not talk of it further
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

This is the same list in Markdown:

```
 - I have a house
    - It has 4 walls,
    - a roof,
    - two windows
    - and a door
         - with a handle
         - and a lock
 - I also have a car
    - But I will not talk of it further
```

The Latex one is really verbose.
I am finding it particularly annoying when writing slides with Beamer.
Nesting 3 deep is rarely a good idea, but having a list that contains 
a few subitems for every item is not bad at all, but will still be uncomfortable verbose.

**Is there a package that provides a alternative syntax for writing lists?**

---

Using a few `defs` can help maybe, but seems hacky

```
\newcommand{\ol}{\begin{itemize} }
\newcommand{\ole}{\end{itemize} }
\newcommand{\li}{\item }
```

Parsing markdown lists syntax seems like it could be done with Lua,
or maybe even with `xargs`, but I am not so great at this kinda thing (yet).

Comment: May be seeing indentation is a bit difficult, but you could, for instance, in a relatively simple way see `-` for `\item` and `--` for `\iitem` where both are a little inteligent and start a new `\begin{itemize}` or end a `\end{itemize}` when necessary.

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101717/17423?

Comment: Isn't it rather a problem of configuring your editor?

Comment: @Bernard: no because the verbosity is not a just a typing problem (though it is that -- a missed end is annoying to find), it is also a reading problem

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look for example at the `easylist`package. It simplifies the process by defining one active character whose number of occurences defines the level of this specific list item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{easylist}
\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}
§ First level
§§ Second level
§§§ Third level
§§§ Again third level
§§§§ Now fourth level
§ First level again
\end{easylist}
\end{document}
```

[image: easylist example]

Comment: Be aware that to use Easylist with Beamer, you must mark the slide as [fragile] http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures#Easylist_package

Comment: How can you set an unsorted list?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ol}[1]{\begin{enumerate}#1\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\ul}[1]{\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\li}[1]{\item{#1}}

\newlength{\shiftwidth}
\setlength{\shiftwidth}{3em}
\newcommand{\info}[1]{\par\hspace*{#1\shiftwidth}$\bullet$\quad}

\begin{document}

Simple ways to make lists less verbosely in \LaTeX:

\ol{%
  \li{Redefine the markup commands to match HTML.}
    \ul{%
       \li{This means turning the list environments into commands.}
       \li{This is actually less verbose than real HTML.}
       \li{You do have to keep track of the end braces and (I think) comment out the newlines.}
    }
   \li{Define commands to insert horizontal space and bullets manually, as shown below.}
}

\info{0} This is level 0.
    \info{1} This is level 1.
        \info{2} And this level 2.

\end{document}
```