# Latex environment for makrdown like lists

Tags: listings, itemize

Is there any environment for making lists (similar to ennumerate or itemize), that would support markdown/wikitext like syntax.

Currently, it is a tedious task to write lists, as one has to write \item for each item (rather than # or * as in wikitext and markdown).

Syntax gets even nastier when you want have nested lists.
I only know outline, but writing \1 (for item at the first level) or \2 (for secound level) is also ugly.

Maybe someone managed to hack around listings support for .md, to render */# not as code but as items?

Comment: Please clarify your main objective(s). Is it that having to write `\item` is tedious?

Comment: `easylist`does what I need. This question can be closed as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199364/a-better-way-to-do-nested-lists