# Is there any package with Markdown support?

Tags: packages, markdown

Sometimes, I have notes where I would not like to convert all portions to Tex format. 
I normally then simply put such contexts under **verbatim**. 
However, this is a rather crude approach. 
So I started to wonder if you can use Markdown inside Tex.
I was originally inspired by this Hamilton's [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134638/showcase-tex-typography-for-tugs-calendar/146178#146178) where he uses R inside Tex, after he made his package available.

Dummy example of data which I would not like to convert to Tex:

```
% http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3458956/
ABC
\textbf{All here are antiseptics} % (used in living tissues on mucosa)
% Antiseptic is often disinfection
1 Iodum (Iodine)
2 Povidonum iodinatum
3 Ichthammolum (ammonia)
4 Viride nitens
5 Kalii permanganas (potassium permanganate)
6 Hydrogeniii peroxidum
7 Benzoylis peroxidum
8 Nitrofuralum
9 Acidum boricum
10 Sulfadiazinum argentum (silver sulfadiazine)
11 Benzalkonium
12 Propanolum/Benzalconium
13 Chlorhexidium
14 Cetylpyridinium
15 Dequalinium/Cinchocainum
16 Colini salicylas (salt of salicylic acid - colini adds here saliva production)
17 Hexetidinum (hexetidine)

% only 120 main drugs in exam - from 6 classes theoretically
% much more studied in practcals

A group
1 Halogen
2 Halogen
3 Aromatic compound
4 Dye compounds
5 Oxidizing agent
6 Oxidizing agent
7 Oxidizing agent
8 Nitrofurans
9 Acids 
10 Heavy metal (silver)
% Synthetic antibacterial
% Antibiotics are produced by living organisms (fungi, bacteria, actinomyces, ...)
...
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
TeXLive: the latest, not the old one in apt-get

Comment: You probably want to use `lex` or some equivalent tool for that.

Comment: you can use LuaTeX with lunamark - https://github.com/jgm/lunamark. It has output format for LaTeX, only escaping of LaTeX special characters must be disabled if one want to mix markdown and LaTeX in the input. I can make some example later

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101731/29873

Comment: May be the package `wiki` or the whole [nicetext bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicetext).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [a new package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/markdown) for the inclusion of Markdown in plain TeX, LaTeX, and ConTeXt documents. Much like the package suggested by Michal in the accepted answer, this package is also based on the Lunamark parser. This time around, the parser was heavily modified, so that it allows the user to control the expansion of Markdown tokens to TeX tokens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\markdownSetup{
  renderers = {
    link     = {#1},        % Render a link as the link label.
    emphasis = {\emph{#1}}, % Render emphasis using `\emph`.
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
  _Hello,_ [Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

The above code produces “*Hello,* Stack Exchange!”. Note that setting up these mappings is not mandatory (though often useful); the defaults should be quite sane. Package authors are encouraged to redefine renderer prototypes (see section 2.2.4 in the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf)) to override the defaults without overriding the user mappings.

Any engine that supports shell access (pdfTeX, XeTeX) can be used, not just LuaTeX. Note, however, that you need to provide the `--shell-escape` option or set `shell_escape=t` in the `texmf.cnf` file when you don't use LuaTeX. This is similar to other packages (such as Geoffrey M. Poore's [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted)) that require shell access.

The package also supports syntax extensions such as citations, fenced code blocks, and other (see section 2.1.2 in the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.pdf)), although I did backport these to Lunamark, so they can now be used with Michal's package as well.

Comment: I am the creator and the maintainer of the package, so I cannot give you an unbiased opinion. I am, however, planning to maintain the package (the maintenance is currently funded as a part of a university research project) and the Overleaf staff think the package works well enough at the moment (http://twitter.com/overleaf/status/763395560682364928) if that adds any credibility.

Comment: Lunamark does not currently support any Markdown syntax extensions for tables, although they are on the roadmap (patches are welcome).

Comment: The package is already present in the latest version of TeX Live 2016. The installation instructions are covered in [README.md](https://github.com/witiko/markdown#installation). Feel free to create the missing folders.

Comment: What do you think about this project https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1646475295/latex-complex-tables-editor/description ? I sent a question to the developer to get clarifications about their aims. It sounds to me more like what you are trying to do.  - - What is the level table support now in the package and `lunamark`?

Comment: It seems to me that the author is aiming to create a graphical table editor that outputs LaTeX code whereas the Markdown package enables writing documents in a lightweight markup language of Markdown -- I do not think there is much overlap at the moment. There is currently no table syntax support in Lunamark, although the `markdown.sty` package allows you to embed tables in CSV (not a very complex markup to be sure) using the content blocks syntax extension.

Comment: The last point is very interesting. Can you point me to some examples. I really would like to use CSV to assist my table use. - - Can you please give also your recommendation if the package is now "almost" ready for extensive note taking with tables? What are major changes compared to 2016 edition?

Comment: Other than the CSVs, there is currently no table support. For a run-down of the available syntax, see the [example document](https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/tree/master/examples). A lot has changed since the (initial) version from TeX Live 2016; see the [release notes](https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/releases) for version 2.0.0 and beyond. There will also be an article introducing the package in the next issue of TUGboat.

Comment: There is now support for tables, see https://github.com/Witiko/markdown/issues/32#issuecomment-484681882.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**:

I've put this code on github - [latexmark](https://github.com/michal-h21/latexmark), and extended little bit.

New package options are provided:

**extensions**: select lunamark extensions

**document**: process whole everything between `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`

**template**: select [Cosmo](http://cosmo.luaforge.net/) template which will be used for printing converted text

new command was added:

```
\markdownfile{filename}
```

typeset markdown file.

---

It is possible to use `lunamark` with `LuaTeX`, but it is little bit harder to install it. You need to add to your local texmf tree (usually ~/texmf/scripts/lua, you may need to create this directory) new directory `lunamark` and copy contents of `standalone/src` directory from [lunamark sources](https://github.com/jgm/lunamark).

Test if that works with command:

```
kpsewhich lunamark.lua
```

path to this file should be printed.

After successful installation, we can create simple lua module for `lunamark` loading, `latexmark.lua`

```
local latexmark = {}
local lunamark = require("lunamark")
local writer = lunamark.writer.latex.new()
local util = lunamark.util
writer.string = function(s) return s end
writer.definitionlist= function(items)
    local buffer = {}
    for _,item in ipairs(items) do
      local defs = {}
      buffer[#buffer + 1] = {"\\item[",item.term,"] ", util.intersperse(item.definitions,"\n")}
    end
    local contents = util.intersperse(buffer, "\n")
    return {"\\begin{description}\n",contents,"\n\\end{description}"}
 end
latexmark.init = function(extensions)
   local extensions = extensions or { smart = true, definition_lists=true}
   latexmark.parser = lunamark.reader.markdown.new(writer, extensions)
end

latexmark.end_env = "%s*\\end{latexmark}"
local buffer = {}
latexmark.callback = function(buf)
  if buf:match(latexmark.end_env) then
    --local ret =  latexmark.process() 
    --table.insert(ret, buf)
    return ret
  end
  buffer[#buffer+1] = buf
  return ''
end

latexmark.process = function()
  local result = latexmark.parser(table.concat(buffer,"\n"))
  buffer = {}
  local lines = string.explode(result,"\n")
  for _, line in ipairs(lines) do
    print(line)
    tex.print(line)
  end
  return lines
end

return latexmark
```

`lunamark` is being initialized and function for LuaTeX's `process_input_filter` is provided. now some simple LaTeX package, `latexmark.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{latexmark}

\RequirePackage{luatexbase}

\directlua{%
  latexmark = require "latexmark"
  latexmark.init()
}


\newenvironment{latexmark}
{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer",latexmark.callback,"latexmark")}}
{\directlua{%
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "latexmark")
    latexmark.process()
}}

\endinput
```

new environment, `latexmark` is provided, it's contents will be converted. It is really easy to use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{latexmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{latexmark}
# Hello world

1. enumerated
2. list

some \LaTeX\ stuff: $a = \sqrt{b}$

what
: it is easy to provide description lists

and also `monospaced`, or *emphatized* texts

\end{latexmark}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some sample file:

Comment: @Masi I know about it, it is indeed more powerful than my code, I use it myself

Comment: It would be great to get some comparison of the two systems. At the moment, I cannot use it because having the bug illustrated in my bounty in my system. - - I made his answer accepted answer here to indicate the recent development in the area.

Comment: the newer package has certainly more features and cleaner interface. my solution is more primitive, but on the other hand it doesn't need to create any temporary files, it can convert markdown on the fly

Comment: The caching in the above package is deliberate to speed up the processing of large documents and to aid debugging, when the intermediary tex document fails to compile. It is also necessary in engines other than LuaTeX.