# Filtering through an external command in LaTeX?

Tags: shell-escape, markdown

Is there any way in LaTeX to define an environment, say,

```
\begin{markdown}
  This will be *processed* as
  [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)!
\end{markdown}
```

which passes the contents of the environment through an external command (such as `pandoc`), then substitutes the processed results back into the document? Essentially, is it possible to replicate the [filter](https://github.com/adityam/filter) ConTeXt module? I've tried various tricks with `bashful` and `\directlua` but with no success.

Comment: Did you check out the posting [Is there any package with Markdown support?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209889/5001)

Comment: AFAIK, the closest analog of filter module in LaTeX is the [pythontex](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex). In principle, you should be able to replicate the functionality of the filter module by an appropriate python script (and then wrap around that using pythontex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing and able to use LuaLaTeX, an extension to an earlier answer given to the posting [Use Markdown-style formatting for bold and italic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236439/5001) may work for you. It doesn't call an external routine (e.g, `pandoc`), though. Instead, it converts selected Markdown-type code into LaTeX-based code.

The code (a) defines a LaTeX environment named `markdown` and (b) sets up a Lua function named `process_simple_markdown` to handle *very simple* cases of markdown-type code. The Lua function is activated inside -- and *only inside* -- `markdown` environments. Lua "captures" are used to process what's inside *pairs* of parentheses and brackets and pairs of triple, double, and single asterisks. The Lua function is assigned to the so-called `process_input_buffer` callback; it therefore operates on the input file at a very early stage, *before* TeX itself does any typesetting-related work.

A strong caveat: Syntax checking is currently somewhere between rudimentary and non-existent. E.g., if you have pairs of asterisks inside a URL string, I have no idea what may happen.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} % for "\href" macro

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
   function process_simple_markdown (line)
      line = string.gsub( line, "%[(.-)%]%((.-)%)", "\\href{%2}{%1}" )
      line = string.gsub( line, "%*%*%*(.-)%*%*%*", "\\textbf{\\textit{%1}}")
      line = string.gsub( line, "%*%*(.-)%*%*",     "\\textbf{%1}" )
      line = string.gsub( line, "%*(.-)%*",         "\\textit{%1}" )
      return line
   end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\markdownon{%
   \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", process_simple_markdown, "process_simple_markdown" )}}
\newcommand\markdownoff{%
   \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback( "process_input_buffer", "process_simple_markdown" )}}
\newenvironment{markdown}{\markdownon}{\markdownoff}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}
  This will be *processed* as [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)!
\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Markdown was actually merely an example of a possible filter, unfortunately - my actual use-case is processing [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/) source and embedding the resulting images. However, the `process_input_buffer` callback appears to be an extremely viable way to capture buffer contents regardless of what they're being used for, so this was a great pointer! Thanks.

Comment: @00Davo: For a slow filter such as PlantUML, you may also want to consider caching the result. In the filter module, I compute the MD5 hash of the entire environment and compare it with previously stored value (stored in the auxiliary file), and re-run the filter only if this value has changed.