# .tex + .md: issue with tables

Tags: apa6, markdown

I would like to use markdown files with latex. A [post](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/441-how-to-write-in-markdown-on-overleaf) on Overleaf really helped me almost solve my issue. The only deal breaker would be inserting tables from markdown into latex. I need help with this. I am very new to latex and have been going back and fourth from markdown. Perhaps I'm in a transition mode.

As you can see I am using the markdown package and inputting sections of my work into the tex file. Everything works well accept for tables. The overleaf post mentions using `contentBlocks` or `inputFencedCode` but I can't find any information about how to use those features.

I'm not totally against just simply taking out the markdown package and writing in latex, but I truly appreciate the simplicity of writing in markdown. So, I was hoping to combine my love for both in this and future projects.

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,floatsintext]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
%\usepackage[hybrid]{markdown} %waiting to see if this is a possibility with tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\title{title}
\shorttitle{title}
\author{author}
\affiliation{affiliation}
\note{date}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\markdownInput{01Intro.md}
\markdownInput{02Framework.md}
\markdownInput{03Methods.md}
\end{document}
```

Here is an example `.md` file I would like to see work in the above `.tex`:

```
# Heading

Some important text here, please refer to the following table:

|        | Important | Information |  Here  | 
|:------:|:---------:|:-----------:|:------:| 
| Week 1 |   null  |   null    | null | 
| Week 2 |   null  |    null   | null | 
| Week 3 |   null  |    null   | null |

I hope this important table has lead to your increased 
understanding of this very important topic. I trust that  
it will.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a minimal document. Unfortunately, however, the one you've posted doesn't really help us because we don't have your included `.md` files.  Can you add an example `.md` file that doesn't work (and explain what the problem is; it's not really clear what "doesn't work" means).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no support for tables in the `markdown` package. See comments [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334851/2693) from the package author.

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to look into [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/), which converts markdown to LaTeX quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of your document which is compilable with `pandoc`.  The command I used to compile it is:

```
 pandoc --standalone --variable documentclass=apa6  --variable classoption=12pt --variable classoption=floatsintext --variable classoption=man  markdown-table.md -o markdown-table.pdf
```

The `.md` file (`markdown-table.md`) contains a mixture of Markdown and LaTeX interspersed.

```
\title{title}
\shorttitle{title}
\author{author}
\affiliation{affiliation}
\note{date}
\abstract{}

\maketitle

# Heading

Some important text here, please refer to the following table:

|        | Important | Information |  Here  |
|:------:|:---------:|:-----------:|:------:|
| Week 1 |   null  |   null    | null |
| Week 2 |   null  |    null   | null |
| Week 3 |   null  |    null   | null |

I hope this important table has lead to your increased
understanding of this very important topic. I trust that
it will.
```

The output of the 3rd page:

[image: output of 3rd page]

Comment: This is so amazing, I don't know how to contain myself! It works! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @hearsay Just remember it's not a panacea, and debugging is harder since the conversion is all hidden from view.  But it is pretty powerful, and for certain kinds of documents, quite useful.