# What preamble or packages do TeX StackExchange answers use?

Tags: preamble

I want to copy some good answers to my local tex editor in order to review sometimes future. There will be many errors since like ** ** means bold, 
 `space` x 4 means writing codes, etc. And sometimes I want to write some answers in local tex editor, and after compile successfully then directly copy to tex.stackexchange.

I want to write following templates :

```
\documentclass{article}
%some packages or newcommand I need to import    


\begin{document}
%I can directly copy some answers in tex.stackexchange
\end{document}
```

What environment(packages, newcommand,etc.) does tex.stachexchange uses? Or how to write an environment(preamble) in LaTeX such that it will be compatible from the syntax in tex.stackexchange?

Comment: TeX.SE doesn't use LaTeX for formatting, it uses Markdown syntax.

Comment: The contents here are not rendered in LaTeX. Posts are written in some kind of markdown/HTML flavour. (There are some ways to render markdown with TeX, e.g. https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown or Pandoc. But TeX itself does not really do that out of the box.)

Comment: See also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101717/converting-markdown-to-latex-in-latex

Comment: @CarLaTeX Or how to write an environment in LaTeX such that it will be compatible from the syntax in tex.stackexchange?

Comment: @maplemaple See the answers to my previous link, it is not easy.

Comment: @Marijin I don't want to compile their codes. I just want to save their whole answer(what they are looking in the website) to a local tex file.

Comment: Ok I see, I misunderstood - but why would you want to save the full answer in LaTeX?

Comment: @Marijin I want to combine many good answers and write a nontrivial example manual for several main topics in LaTeX (e.g. graph, table, beamer etc.)

Comment: @maplemaple: An admirable purpose! Hope you succeed.

Comment: @maplemaple Well, you can always write your own! After having a preamble you only have to re-format questions and answers a bit more. But I'm afraid you can't import questions and answers here directly from a link, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the mwe you provided (pasted) in its native state we can see it is part of a web page and would need some serious decoding to restore it as you intended it to look.

```html
<pre class="lang-tex prettyprint prettyprinted"><code><span class="kwd">\documentclass</span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">article</span><span class="pun">}</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="com">%some packages or newcommand I need to import    </span><span class="pln">


</span><span class="kwd">\begin</span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">document</span><span class="pun">}</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="com">%I can directly copy some answers in tex.stackexchange</span><span class="pln">
</span><span class="kwd">\end</span><span class="pun">{</span><span class="pln">document</span><span class="pun">}</span><span class="pln">  </span></code></pre>
```

However if we simply cut and paste as plain text to ANY editor from simple notepad to the most complex of systems then it will be compatible, compliable and compilable

> \documentclass{article}
>   %some packages or newcommand I need to
>   import
>   \begin{document}
>   %I can directly copy some answers in tex.stackexchange
>   Hello maplemaple
>   \end{document}

```
\pretend this is latex {class}
It may not be immediately apparent that in most browsers if you
double click the start or end of a structured code block like this  
it will be possible to copy to clipboard, try me at start \ or here >
```

So there is generally no need to alter / decode answers for use in your editor other than any related comments to a correct answer, assuming you know it is correct :-)

For wider discussions on how's and why's you could look at [Feature request: Better support for copying code from question or answers](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/feature-request-better-support-for-copying-code-from-question-or-answers) and the related links at the side of that discussion.