# Math symbols in text editor

Tags: amsmath

I wonder if there is any way one can sync latex with a text editor such that the symbols appear in my text editor. I like to summarize courses and other things in text editor and dont really want to write a LaTeX file for it.

Comment: Welcome ! I am afraid I do not understand your demand at all, and I feel I won't be the only one. This place is a LaTeX related forum, where you say you *dont really want to write a LaTeX file*...

Comment: Ah okey, I'll attach a picture which might help. I want to be able to write like this https://i.imgur.com/Kso9NXF.png but that I can use latex commands to get symbols in my text editor.

Comment: A previous question relating to parsing Markdown as LaTeX: 
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101717/converting-markdown-to-latex-in-latex.

Comment: Even with the linked example I don't understand what you want.  The "LaTeX code" in the example isn't even compilable without errors.  For example, on line 111 there is the string `V\otimesW`.  If you wanted the visual form of the symbols, then direct Unicode entry is supported by some editors with utf-8 input, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking.

Comment: the visual of the symbols is what i want, i know that some of the lines in the text isnt correct but they are mostly for me to know what i mean, and have latex style since thats what i know