# Fancyhead Display Custom Shorten Version Of \leftmark

Tags: fancyhdr, pandoc

Good day,

I would like to display a custom shorten version of the \leftmark with Fancyhdr.

Ideally it would be some type of switch with a case for each chapter.

Right now this is what the header's code looks like:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark} % I would like to implement the string converter here
```

In pseudo-code it could be something like this:

```
var headerText = \leftmark

switch headerText:
  case "The very long chapter name":
    headerText = "The chapter name"
  case "Chapter two is also very long":
    headerText = "Chapter two"
  ...

\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape headerText}
```

An important point in what I'm trying to do is that the output string could be totally different from the original.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I'm using Pandoc to convert a Markdown file into a PDF. So it would be nice to have a solution compatible with this method of generating books. Thank you!

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I display a short chapter name in the header and a long chapter name in the ToC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6862/5764)

Comment: @Werner I don't know, the one provided by default by Pandoc I guess. Do you know how I can see what `\documentclass` I'm using?

Comment: @Werner one thing I forgot to mention is that I'm using Pandoc to generate a PDF from Markdown. Do you think I could integrate the code given in this answer directly into my Markdown document? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6866/260078

Comment: Yes, you should be able to as far as I understand. I'm not that familiar with the Pandoc settings for conversion. [This](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2004) does point to some option where it keeps the `.tex` output, from where you can see what `\documentclass` is being used. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246871/5764) shows it's possible to sprinkle LaTeX throughout the markdown code.

Comment: @Werner I did a `--verbose` run and got this in the output `Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class`. After doing some research I understood that I should use a `\documentclass:book` in order to access the `\chater{}` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that more or less implements your pseudo code. You can add this in the beginning of your converted LaTeX code (`pandoc` output).

**Update: we have to be careful not to use this trick for chapters that put non-alphabetic characters in `\leftmark` or in their title. See below.**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

% Pseudo code:

% var headerText = \leftmark

% switch headerText:
%   case "The very long chapter name":
%     headerText = "The chapter name"
%   case "Chapter two is also very long":
%     headerText = "Chapter two"
%   ...

% \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape headerText}

% Implementation:

\newcommand\chaptertitle[2]{\expandafter\def\csname=#1=\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\shorttitle[1]{\expandafter\csname=\leftmark=\endcsname}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\chaptertitle{One chapter with a very large chapter title}{Chapter One}
\chaptertitle{Another chapter title that really is much too long}{Chapter Two}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \shorttitle{\leftmark}} % I would like to implement the string converter here
                                % 
\begin{document}
\chapter{One chapter with a very large chapter title}

\lipsum

\chapter{Another chapter title that really is much too long}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This gives problems for chapters that use non-alphabetic characters in `\markboth`, for example `\tableofcontents` and similar ones. You can solve this by using the original header for these:

**Update 2: The `\newpage` after `\tableofcontents` should be a `\cleardoublepage` (if documentclass `book` is used), otherwise there might be an empty page that still uses the bad `\leftmark`.** Actually it is nicer to do a `\newpage` first, then change the header to be empty, then do a `\cleardoublepage`, and then change the header to its new form.  In this case, if there is an empty page it will not have a header, which looks nicer. Such a page is always an even page, so we just change the header for even pages. So that is done with this update.

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{Index}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\fancyhead[RE]{}
\cleardoublepage
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \shorttitle{\leftmark}}
```

[image]

Comment: Good day Sir, I have been trying to implement your solution but now I get this error `Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.

[1]
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
l.90 \mainmatter` Do you know how I could solve it?

Comment: I created a file `header.tex` that I call in the pandoc command like this: `pandoc +RTS -Ksize -RTS -f gfm -V documentclass:book -H ./header.tex ...`.

Comment: Here is what the code looks like: `\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\newcommand\chaptertitle[2]{\expandafter\def\csname=#1=\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\shorttitle[1]{\expandafter\csname=\leftmark=\endcsname}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\chaptertitle{Le Sainct Evangile de Jesus Christ ; selon Sainct Matthieu.}{Sainct Matthieu}
\fancyhead[RE]{\slshape \shorttitle{\leftmark}}
`

Comment: Without seeing how you use the `hyperref` package, it is difficult to find out what is going wrong. Ideally you would give us a small document that shows the error.

Comment: Alright, I created this Gist with 3 files https://gist.github.com/RilDev/a5da407affd43daa7df36b05f6c39c3b: `nt.text` is the original file, `nt.tex` is the output produced by `pandoc -s nt.text -o nt.tex` and `error` is the error I get when using `md2pdf.sh`, a custom script to generate the final PDF. `md2pdf.sh` is found here: https://github.com/RilDev/olivetan/tree/master/tools/pandoc. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'll have a look.

Comment: The problem is caused by the `\tableofcontents` that uses `\markboth` with non-alphabetic stuff in it, most notable `\protect` and `\MakeUppercase`. `\chaptertitle` and `\shorttitle` can't handle this. So for these kinds of chapters use the original header without the `\shorttitle` trick.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for taking the time to debug my project. I confirm your solution is working. But not together with a table of content or a title page. No problem, I'll generate multiple PDF, cut them and assemble them together with `pdftk`! If anyone is interested, I'll be adding the scripts here: https://github.com/RilDev/olivetan/tree/master/tools,