# Filecontents and newenvironment issue

Tags: listings, environments, external-files, filecontents, content-replication

I need to write some inlined code on an external file, then load it with `listings`. I would like to define a new environment, but if I do, `filecontents` does not save the first line of code (see MWE):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newenvironment{MyNewEnvironment}[2]{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \csname filecontents*\endcsname{\temp}%
  #2%
}%
{\csname endfilecontents*\endcsname%
 \lstinputlisting{\temp}%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{MyNewEnvironment}{foo.txt}%
one
two
three
four
five

\end{MyNewEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

The resulting foo.txt contains:

```
two
three
four
five
```

Comment: You can't use `filecontents*` like that; I suggest you to check `fancyvrb` that provides a way to write verbatim to another file.

Comment: @egreg i just skimmed the docs of the `filecontents` package, and i'm not sure what actually _is_ wrong with flodd's use of the command.  what is the rule that prevents such use?

Comment: @wasteofspace Probably you're right, as karlkoeller's answers shows. However, I find `VerbatimOut` much more flexible.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second argument of environment `MyNewEnvironment`? It causes the trouble, because it is not read in the control of `\filecontents*` with its changed catcodes and line ends. Removing the second argument solves your problem as shown in [karlkoeller's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130296/16967).

Comment: I see... I guess I just have misunderstood how `newenvironment` works :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest using `fancyvrb` and `xparse`, that allows also to pass options to `\lstinputlisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xparse,listings}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyNewEnvironment}{O{}m}
  {\VerbatimOut{#2}}
  {\endVerbatimOut\lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyNewEnvironment}[columns=fullflexible]{foo.txt}
one
two
three
four
five

\end{MyNewEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `O{}m` denote? I cannot find an explanation in xparse.pdf.

Comment: @koppor It denotes an optional argument with empty default value and a mandatory argument.

Comment: Comparing the environments, filecontents converts each tab character to exactly one space, while VerbatimOut converts each tab character to the value of tabsize spaces. For raw tabs scontents can be used, although unfortunately that package is not extensible [Create external file (like a Makefile) whit real tabs - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354588/) // Another option is [luatex - In LuaLaTeX, how do I pass the content of an environment to Lua verbatim? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38150/)

Answer (score 14):

Probably it's not the right way to use `filecontents*`, as egreg says in his comment.

Anyway, changing your MWE to

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newenvironment{MyNewEnvironment}[1]{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \csname filecontents*\endcsname{\temp}%
}%
{\csname endfilecontents*\endcsname%
 \lstinputlisting{\temp}%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{MyNewEnvironment}{foo.txt}
one
two
three
four
five
\end{MyNewEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

works fine for me.

Comment: +1 This solution seems very good ... despite the comments of egreg. ;-)