# Create external file (like a Makefile) whit real tabs

Tags: external-files, makefile, directlua

I'm trying to generate a external Makefile (and others) file using latex and the filecontents or fancyvrb package. As the `\t` (tabs) characters in input file are converted to space in output file (see [output tabulation into a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58732/how-to-output-a-tabulation-into-a-file), i have decided to do a little trick using a little Lua (i know you can with `sed` or `perl`).

As I am not very familiar with `Lua` but written the following code (The forum convert real tabs to space`example.tex`):

```
% example.tex
% arara: lualatex : {draft: yes,action: nonstopmode}
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { files:[example.aux,example.log,Makefile.tmp,Makefile.tab] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\begin{document} 

The original Makefile whit real tabs (show whit arrow)
%% forum convert tabs into space...replace whit real tab (show in red)
\begin{Verbatim}[obeytabs, showtabs, tab=\rightarrowfill, tabcolor=red,showspaces, spacecolor=blue]
clean: clean-test 
    rm -f *.bbl *.bcf *.bib *.blg *.xdy # biblatex

distclean: clean
    rm -f *.cls *.sty *.clo *.tar.gz *.tds.zip README

%.cls: %.dtx
    tex $<

%.pdf: %.dtx
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error $<
\end{Verbatim}

Write in external file (Makefile.tab)

\begin{VerbatimOut}{Makefile.tab}
clean: clean-test 
    rm -f *.bbl *.bcf *.bib *.blg *.xdy # biblatex

distclean: clean
    rm -f *.cls *.sty *.clo *.tar.gz *.tds.zip README

%.cls: %.dtx
    tex $<

%.pdf: %.dtx
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error $<
\end{VerbatimOut}

Read Makefile.tmp file, (tabs are convert in space)
\VerbatimInput[obeytabs, showtabs, tab=\rightarrowfill, tabcolor=red,showspaces, spacecolor=blue]{Makefile.tab}

%%
\ifluatex
Create lua funtion only in lualatex
\begin{filecontents*}{maketab.lua}
-- maketab
local open = io.open

local function read_file(filename)
    local file = open(filename, "r") -- r read mode
    if not file then return nil end
    local slurp = file:read "*all" -- reads the whole file (slurp)
    file:close()
    return slurp
end

local content = read_file("Makefile.tmp");
content=content:gsub("TAB ", "\t")

-- Create new Makefile.mk (pdfTeX need ext)
outwhitmk = io.open("Makefile.mk", "w")
    outwhitmk:write(content)
outwhitmk:close()

-- Create new Makefile (no ext)
outreal = io.open("Makefile", "w")
    outreal:write(content)
outreal:close()
\end{filecontents*}
\else
\fi

Write a external Makefile.tmp changue tab for TAB \newline

\begin{filecontents*}{Makefile.tmp}
clean: clean-test 
TAB rm -f *.bbl *.bcf *.bib *.blg *.xdy # biblatex

distclean: clean
TAB rm -f *.cls *.sty *.clo *.tar.gz *.tds.zip README

%.cls: %.dtx
TAB tex $<

%.pdf: %.dtx
TAB pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error $<
\end{filecontents*}

Show external Makefile.tmp \newline

\VerbatimInput[obeytabs, showtabs, tab=\rightarrowfill, tabcolor=red,showspaces, spacecolor=blue]{Makefile.tmp}

Now using directlua maketab.lua to reverse TAB to real tab character\newline

\ifluatex
\directlua{dofile("maketab.lua")}
Show correct MakeFile (LuaTeX don't need ext)
\VerbatimInput[obeytabs, showtabs, tab=\rightarrowfill, tabcolor=red,showspaces, spacecolor=blue]{{Makefile}}
\else
Show correct MakeFile (pdfTeX)
\VerbatimInput[obeytabs, showtabs, tab=\rightarrowfill, tabcolor=red,showspaces, spacecolor=blue]{Makefile.mk}
\fi
\end{document}
```

and I have two doubts about it:

1. Is the correct way to create a Makefile file from LaTeX, or is there any package that can do this (I do not want to re-invent the wheel).
2. Referring to the Lua code(`maketab.lua`), is possible to rewrite the code in the following direct `\directlua{dofile("maketab.lua",filein.ext,fileout[.ext]?)}`? , Pass the name of the input file with extension and the name of the output file with optional extension.

Grateful in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to write a Makefile using LaTeX? `filecontents` should be used before `\documentclass`.

Comment: The truth is I'm trying to document a scrip (perl / c ++) in latex and then pass them DTX. And the` \ t` characters are important for the files generated (not just Makefile, Readme.md, source.c, etc ...)

Comment: For LuaTeX there's another solution [luatex - In LuaLaTeX, how do I pass the content of an environment to Lua verbatim? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38150/in-lualatex-how-do-i-pass-the-content-of-an-environment-to-lua-verbatim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself, you can use the `scontents` package, and you don't need to write a `lua` script to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\begin{document}
The original Makefile whit real tabs (show red arrow)
\begin{Verbatim}[obeytabs, showtabs, tab=\rightarrowfill, tabcolor=red]
clean: clean-test
	rm -f *.bbl *.bcf *.bib *.blg *.xdy
distclean: clean
	rm -f *.cls *.sty *.clo *.tar.gz *.tds.zip README
\end{Verbatim}
Write in external file (Makefile.tab)
\begin{scontents}[write-out=Makefile.tab]
clean: clean-test
	rm -f *.bbl *.bcf *.bib *.blg *.xdy
distclean: clean
	rm -f *.cls *.sty *.clo *.tar.gz *.tds.zip README
\end{scontents}
Read Makefile.tab file (show red arrow)
\VerbatimInput[obeytabs, showtabs, tab=\rightarrowfill, tabcolor=red]{Makefile.tab}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: `scontents` is unfortunately not extensible (use in custom defined environment). -- Also if you use XeTeX then there's a special note. Read "3.2 The TAB character" section in `scontents` manual and/or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58740/250119 -- It's also possible to use `\VerbatimOut`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570758/250119