# Verbatim write in Plain TeX

Tags: verbatim, plain-tex, write

I am trying to write verbatim text into a file in Plain TeX. In LaTeX I could use the `verbatim` package. My goal is using Asymptote in Plain TeX. So I need something that works like `\verbatim@start` from `verbatim.sty`.

MWE:

```
% Plain LuaTeX
\catcode`@=11
% from latex.ltx
\long\def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3{%
    \let\reserved@d=#1%
    \def\reserved@a{#2}%
    \def\reserved@b{#3}%
    \futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}
\def\@ifnch{%
    \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
    \let\reserved@c\@xifnch
    \else
    \ifx\@let@token\reserved@d
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@a
    \else
    \let\reserved@c\reserved@b
    \fi
    \fi
    \reserved@c}
\def\:{\let\@sptoken= } \:  % this makes \@sptoken a space token
\def\:{\@xifnch} \expandafter\def\: {\futurelet\@let@token\@ifnch}

\def\@makeother#1{\catcode`#1=12\relax}

Let's try to write.

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=temp.tmp\relax

\def\verbatimwrite{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12\relax
    %\let\do\@makeother\dospecials%%%%%%% PROBLEM! (A)
    \@verbatimwrite}

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\gdef\@verbatimwrite#1^^M{% Every line must be written separately to save the line breaks.
    \immediate\write\file{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \@ifnextchar\endverbatimwrite\endgroup\@verbatimwrite}% detect the end of verbatim (B)
\endgroup

\let\endverbatimwrite\relax

\verbatimwrite
123#;^{t}
äöüß

4567\undefined
\endverbatimwrite

\immediate\closeout\file

\bye
```

There are 2 problems (also as comments in the code):

- (A): Where do I have to change all the other catcodes? It should be possible for example to write unbalanced braces. If this is done correctly I think the `\unexpanded` command is not needed any more.
- (B): Do you have an idea how to improve the detection of `\endverbatimwrite`? I think my method is really poor.

Thanks.

Comment: For future users who might come across this question -- if you want to define a new environment that captures the argument verbatim and does something else with it in LaTeX,  there are already packages to do that -- see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130298/250119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were changing the catcodes at the right moment. The problem was that after `\let\do\@makeother \dospecials` the guard `\endverbatimwrite` is not a control sequence anymore, but the backslash character plus a sequence of 16 letters. This made your code fail because your `\@ifnextchar` test looks for the *control sequence* `\endverbatimwrite`, which is never found.

As for detecting `\endverbatimwrite`, you don't need to search for it after every line (you can, but you don't have to). The biggest problem is, again, due to the catcode changes: you don't have `\endverbatimwrite` anymore, you have `\` `e` `n` `d` `v` `e` `r` `b` `a` `t` `i` `m` `w` `r` `i` `t` `e`, which is completely different (and much harder to find with `\@ifnextchar`; you'd need a loop of some sort, more or less like `listings` detects the end of the environment). It's much easier to just define a delimited macro that looks for the string `\endverbatimwrite` with the correct catcodes.

Usually the algorithm for a verbatim environment (the simple ones, of course) is:
1) Grab arguments (optional arguments, file name to write or, in this case, the write stream); 2) `\begingroup`; 3) `\catcode`s; 4) Grab the contents of the command/environment; and 5) `\endgroup` and process the grabbed characters (the order of these last two may vary).

Here's a modified version of your code (based some of it form [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460917/134574)):

```
\catcode`@=11

\def\@makeother#1{\catcode`#112\relax}
\def\verbatimwrite#1{%
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\^^M=13
    \newlinechar`\^^M
    \let\do\@makeother \dospecials
    \verbwrite@cleanup#1}
\begingroup
  \lccode`\?=`\\
  \lowercase{\endgroup% \
\def\verbwrite@other#1#2?endverbatimwrite{%
  \immediate\write#1{\unexpanded\expandafter
    {\verbwrite@strip@newline#2\relax}}%
  \endgroup}}
\begingroup
  \catcode`\^^M=13
  \gdef\verbwrite@cleanup#1#2^^M{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \else \errmessage{Wrong input `#2' discarded}%
    \fi
    \verbwrite@other#1}
  \gdef\verbwrite@strip@newline#1^^M\relax{#1}
\endgroup

Let's try to write.

\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file=temp.tmp\relax

\verbatimwrite\file
123#;^{t}
äöüß}

4567\undefined{
\endverbatimwrite

\immediate\closeout\file

\bye
```

The output file contains:

```
123#;^{t}
äöüß}

4567\undefined{
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand why `\verbwrite@cleanup` is needed. What does it prevent?

Comment: @user125730 When `\verbatimwrite` does its thing, the end of that line is tokenized as `^^M`, so you get a leading empty line in the output file. `\verbwrite@cleanup` removes that first `^^M` and ensures that you didn't write any code in that same line (like `\verbatimwrite\file abc<newline>`). To see the difference in the output, just replace the `\verbwrite@cleanup` in the definition of `\verbatimwrite` by `\verbwrite@other`.

Comment: Another question: Is `\unexpanded` still needed? When I delete it nothing changes. (`...\immediate\write#1{\verbwrite@strip@newline#2\relax}...`)

Comment: @user125730 I added the `\unexpanded` for the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/460917/3) because (pdf)LaTeX makes characters like `äöüß` active to cope with Unicode in 8-bit engines, so without `\unexpanded` the `\write` will expand them and BOOM! :-) For LuaTeX (Plain TeX in general, for that matter, except for Knuth's TeX) you probably don't need the `\unexpanded`. Though it doesn't harm either...

Comment: So how does PDFLaTeX avoid the expansion of UTF8 characters? :D When you write something like `\chapter{äöüß}` there is no problem. `äöüß` will appear correctly in the `toc` file.

Comment: I tried this out now with PDFLaTeX, It seems that the active characters are made robust.

Comment: @user125730 Because `\chapter` internally uses `\protected@write` to do the writing. If you changed that to `\write` (or simply did `\write\file{äöüß}`) it would break.

Comment: No... I tried `\immediate\write\file{Ääüöß}` in PDFLaTeX. The file contains `Ääüö\T1\ss`. :D

Comment: @user125730 To break it doesn't necessarily need to throw an error :-) I wouldn't consider that correct output. And that's probably because you have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` loaded. Try without `fontenc`.

Comment: You are right. :D After removing `fontenc` there is only garbage in the file. :D

Comment: @user125730 Not garbage, it's just the expansion of `Ääüöß`. You can even input the file later: `\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\file
\immediate\openout\file temp.tmp
\immediate\write\file{Ääüöß}
\immediate\closeout\file
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\OT1{\csname OT1\endcsname}
\input temp.tmp
\end{document}`. However, from the point of view of readability :-)