# \verb like macro passing argument to Lua

Tags: luatex, verbatim

I'm quite new to `\LaTeX`, but wanted to create a little macro much like `\verb`.
Specifically, I'm writing a little package, in which I would like to pass an argument (that will quite often be containing special characters like `%`, `#`, `}`,...) to `Lua`. I know it's possible  by defining an environment ([see this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191328/how-to-pass-a-latex-argument-verbatim-to-lua)).

However, I can't find any solution to pass such an argument by a single command. At least not without first save a verbatim text to a variable and then passing it as argument, which isn't quite as practical. All `\verb`-related packages seem to either be focusing on the `verbatim` environment, or on a version allowing to use it *inside* a macro - which doesn't help me.

Edit: a small code snippet to clarify: I have already something like:

<package.lua>

```
function process(input)
    -- do something with input
end
```

<document.tex>

```
\passToLua¨<some text with special characters %$[+=\#>¨
```

But I can't properly define a command that accepts a parameter with these special characters - ideally it would look something like the this (although I know it will probably look much uglier):

<package.sty>

```
\providecommand{\passToLua}[1]{  % This will need adapting as it doesn't accept %, #, ... in it's argument
    \directlua{
        require("package")
        process([[#1]])
    }
}
```

Anyone got an idea?
A huge thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't give many clues but `\newcommand\foo[1]{\directlua{s="\luaescapestring{\detokenize{#1}}"}` may be what you are looking for

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the quick answer, however I search something else. I edited my  question and hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a verbatim (`v`) argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\passToLua{v}{\directlua{
     print ("\string\n======\string\n")
     print ([[#1]])
     print ("\string\n======\string\n")
    }}
\begin{document}

\passToLua{a string with # \ and %}

\end{document}
```

Which will print

```
======

a string with # \ and %

======
```

to the terminal

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for characters \, %, { and } too?

Comment: @WouterVermeulen it does work for them, as I showed. if you want a mis matched { you can use verb syntax using any unused character `\passtolua| %{ |` will pass space, percent, open brace space.