# In LuaLaTeX, how do I pass the content of an environment to Lua verbatim **Without displaying it** in a beamer frame?

Tags: luatex

In this [question / answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38150/in-lualatex-how-do-i-pass-the-content-of-an-environment-to-lua-verbatim) : one pass verbatim `latex` material to `lua`, but `latex` displays this material by him self. If one suppress the two lines :

```
local buf_without_end = mybuf:gsub("\\end{foobar}\n","")
print(string.format("Lua: %q", buf_without_end))
```

the material doesn't disapear. I'd like to modify this material using lua code and display it after.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{luacode,tikz}

\directlua{dofile("verb.lua")}

\newenvironment{LuaVerb}{%
    \directlua{start_recording()}}{%
    \directlua{stop_recording()}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

% pass the material to lua
\begin{LuaVerb}
    hello word
\end{LuaVerb}

% use of this material, but with or witout this line
% the material is displayed

%\directlua{print_recording()}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`verb.lua`

```
tp = tex.print

mybuf = ""

function readbuf( buf )
    mybuf = mybuf .. buf .. "\n" 
end

function start_recording()
    luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', readbuf, 'readbuf')
end

function stop_recording()
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback('process_input_buffer', 'readbuf')
end

function print_recording()
    local buf_without_end = mybuf:gsub("\\end{LuaVerb}\n","")
    print(string.format("Lua: %q", buf_without_end))
    mybuf = ""
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to pass lines to LaTeX, you have to return empty string from the callback, otherwise callback pass the line if return value is `nil`. Because you don't return any value, nil is used implicitly. And because LaTeX doesn't process input anymore, you have to parse input for `\end{LuaVerb}` from Lua side, otherwise you would grab all lines until the end:

```
local end_verb = '%s*\\end{LuaVerb}'

function readbuf( buf )
    if buf:match(end_verb) then 
        return buf 
    end
    mybuf = mybuf .. buf .. "\n" 
    return ""
end
```

Now there is some strange issue with `beamer`, which is maybe caused by how `frames` are processed, because no output is printed with `print_recording()`. But when I changed document class to `article`, I got:

```
(/opt/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/mcb.lua)))) (./jej.aux)Lua: 
"    hello word\
"
```

Comment: It works quite fine. I use Texlive 2014 and both beamer and article output Hello world on the console output, but the text displayed by lua `tex.print(mybuf)` is followed an Omega ???

Comment: @Tarass I am still on `TL 2013`, so maybe this issue is fixed in recent `beamer`. Do you mean that `omega` character is added after `Hello world`?

Comment: Yes it comes from the `\n`. but it wanishes with loading `fontspec`. It's normal I think. Thank you very much.

Comment: Still a problem, it works with beamer outside a `frame`, but in a `frame` the LuaVerb text is not hidden. I had to store the latex material in LuaVerb outside the `frame` and then I can use it in the `frame`.

Comment: @Tarass I think that `beamer` process frame in a special way, because of overlays and similar fetures. the solution could be to use buffer reader to read whole document and parse the document for `\begin/`\end{LuaVerb}` to start/stop processing

Comment: One way could be to store the latex material in different buffers (name given as parameter by the latex command) outside the frame and called back in the frame with the same name. It's not a problem if one can do otherwise.